# How to sum/group by rows that w/ hour format(120:15:10) in C# like in SQL - SELECT SUM (col1), col 2, col3 GROUP BY col2, col3

Tags: c#, sql-server

Problem:
I have a sql database with C# widowsform app with datagridview to show results.
I import data from csv with streamreader.
And I need to make a SELECT SUM([col1]), [col2], [col3] GROUP BY [col2], [col3]

But the column that I need to SUM is nvarchar representing Hours that have the format "000:00:00"

Example:

DB columns:
occurrence_number|solution_group|timein_sgroup

SQL Comamand:Select sum(timein_sgroup), occurence_number, solution_group Group by occurence_number, solution_group

resume: I need the sum of hours in a column(occurence_number) with results grouped by two columns(occurence_number and solution_group)

It's a system that calculates the total time that a support group stayed working with/in the occurrence.

I need a result like this = how much hours an occurence stayed with in a solution group:

```
  occnum | groupnamelvl | total hours(SUM)
------------------------------------------
  occ001 | sgrouplevel2 | 120:10:10
  occ002 | sgrouplevel1 | 20:30:15
  occ001 | sgrouplevel1 | 05:15:00
  occ010 | sgrouplevel3 | 105:05:00
```

I saw a lot of topics about sum Hour showing a result with more than 24 hours but the solutions does not work when i have alredy a column with rows data like this:

```
  occnum | groupnamelvl | hours to sum
------------------------------------------
  occ001 | sgrouplevel2 | 120:15:10
  occ001 | sgrouplevel2 | 30:10:40
  occ001 | sgrouplevel2 | 110:30:00
```

How to sum this column and show result like:

```
  occnum | groupnamelvl | Total_Hours
------------------------------------------
  occ001 | sgrouplevel2 | 260:55:50
```

I use this but its only work with data mior tahn 24h and the result can bem more than 24 but minor than 99:

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,
DATEADD(Minute, 
SUM(
DATEPART(SECOND,CONVERT(datetime,[colunm],8)) + 60 * 
DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,[colunm],8)) + 3600 * 
DATEPART(HOUR,CONVERT(datetime,[colunm],8))
) /60, '00:00:00'), 108) AS [TOTAL]  FROM tb
```

C# part with query:

```
        Database1DataSet ds = new Database1DataSet();

        string strSQL = "that query";
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\App_sqlce35\App\DATA\Database1.sdf");

        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter(strSQL, conn);

        try 
            {
                conn.Open();
                ds.Tables.Add("historico");
                ds.Tables["historico"].BeginLoadData();
                da.Fill(ds.Tables["historico"]);
                ds.Tables["historico"].EndLoadData();
                tb_histstatusDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables["historico"];
```

**New code with help from @AsadAli works fine but i can´t group by:**

```
        SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\App_sqlce35\DATA\Database1.sdf");
        SqlCeCommand cmdselect = new SqlCeCommand("select [col0], [col1], [col2], from tb_histstatus WHERE [col6] <>'';", conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCeDataReader res = cmdselect.ExecuteReader();
            List<string> times = new List<string>();
            while (res.Read())
            {
                times.Add((string)res.GetValue(2));
            }
            int[] result = new int[3];
            foreach (string time in times)
            {
                string[] parts = time.Split(':');
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    result[i] += Convert.ToInt32(parts[i]);
                }
            }
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(result[1] * 60 + result[2]);
            result[0] += ts.Hours; result[1] = ts.Minutes; result[2] = ts.Seconds;
            string resultString = string.Join(":", result);
            MessageBox.Show("Total: " + resultString);
        }
```

Comment: What is the datatype of this column?

Comment: Use those values to make a DateTime object and sum with that. Have you tried this already?

Comment: I set it to NVARCHAR so i try to cast and convert but only work when i have hours  minor than 24 and i get  result more thans 24 hours but only until 99:00:00

Comment: What about taking each part of the time (Hours, minutes and seconds) separately and summing them? You could use `string.Split(':')` to split the time. If this is unclear I can post an example.

Comment: On a sidenote, the result is `260:55:50`, not `160:55:50`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what I'd do:

```
int[] result = new int[3]; //Assuming the format is always as in OP
string[] times = { "120:15:10", "30:10:40", "110:30:00" };
foreach (string time in times)
{
    string[] parts = time.Split(':');
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] += Convert.ToInt32(parts[i]);
    }
}
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(result[1] * 60 + result[2]);
result[0] += ts.Hours; result[1] = ts.Minutes; result[2] = ts.Seconds;
string resultString = string.Join(":", result);
```

Output: `260:55:50`

Edit: I've updated my code to match the correct format.

Edit 2: Here's how you'd use it.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source=\App_sqlce35\DATA\Database1.sdf");
SqlCeCommand cmdselect = new SqlCeCommand("select [col0], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6] from tb_histstatus WHERE [col6] <>'';", conn);
try
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCeDataReader res = cmdselect.ExecuteReader();
    List<string> times = new List<string>();
    while (res.Read()) {
        times.Add((string)res.GetValue(6));
    }                
    int[] result = new int[3];
    foreach (string time in times)
    {
        string[] parts = time.Split(':');
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
        {
            result[i] += Convert.ToInt32(parts[i]);
        }
    }          
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(result[1] * 60 + result[2]);
    result[0] += ts.Hours; result[1] = ts.Minutes; result[2] = ts.Seconds;
    string resultString = string.Join(":", result);
    MessageBox.Show("Total: " + resultString);
}
```

Comment: @AsadAli - It's Working! Thank you very much, you give me a great help and I learned a lot with this question/solution!

Comment: One more question if need to group by two columns.
My original problem was that i need to sum hours group by solutioncode and area

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? Edit your original question to add details please.

Comment: @AsadAli  Sorry, I edit and put a description and example now!

Comment: @LuisUssuy I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I need the sum of hours in a column(occurence_number) with results grouped by two columns(occurence_number and solution_group) It's a system that calculates the total time that a support group stayed with the occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void TimeCalc()
    {
        string[] t1 = "120:15:10".Split(':');
        string[] t2 = "30:10:40".Split(':');
        string[] t3 = "110:30:00".Split(':');

        TimeSpan ts1 = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(t1[0]), Convert.ToInt32(t1[1]), Convert.ToInt32(t1[2]));
        TimeSpan ts2 = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(t2[0]), Convert.ToInt32(t2[1]), Convert.ToInt32(t2[2]));
        TimeSpan ts3 = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(t3[0]), Convert.ToInt32(t3[1]), Convert.ToInt32(t3[2]));

        TimeSpan ts = ts1.Add(ts2).Add(ts3);

        Console.WriteLine((ts.Hours + (ts.Days * 24)).ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString());
    }
```

This works. Kind of not elegant, but works...

Pretend that "times": is a list of strings[], then you can do something like this:

```
string[] t1 = "120:15:10".Split(':');
string[] t2 = "30:10:40".Split(':');
string[] t3 = "110:30:00".Split(':');

List<string[]> times = new List<string[]>();
times.Add(t1);
times.Add(t2);
times.Add(t3);

TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();

foreach (var item in times)
{
    TimeSpan tsa = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt32(item[0]), Convert.ToInt32(item[1]), Convert.ToInt32(item[2]));
    ts = (ts == TimeSpan.Zero) ? tsa : ts.Add(tsa);
}
Console.WriteLine((ts.Hours + (ts.Days * 24)).ToString() + ":" + ts.Minutes.ToString() + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString());
```

Comment: This looks good but I need to say that I'm not a C# programmer, i just start now with programing and dont know how to use it with my query :(

Comment: well, this particular part will come after you got your results from query. Once you got your values, then you can manipulate them. 1. get data from db; 2. verify that they are strings and in correct format; 3. calculate; 4. do whatever else you need to with the result.

Comment: I will try this and then ill give you a feedback

Comment: Im sorry but i really dont know how to implement this cause if my query have about 100 rows and how i sum(timespan ts.add) if the query result i from one column and many rows, i need to use  while?

Comment: Sorry, but it doe not work cause i need it to be more dinamic, in this way I'll need to put every line string[]t
But manually works!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have choosed the wrong datatype for your column. Instead of storing these values as strings or datetime you could simply use an integer column where you store just the total of seconds.

```
 260:50:55 = (260*60*60) + (50 * 60) + 55 = 939350 seconds.
```

Now you have a perfectly manageable value for SUM aggregate function.

Just when you need to show the value you apply the formula to separate the part values

```
int seconds = GetDurationFromDatabase(); // IE=939350;
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,seconds);
Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}", ts.Days * 24 + ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

Comment: i had try but could not importe data converting to int SQL Server gives me error and the same problem using StreamReader from csv to database.